# Вернуть уникальные значения в domBuilder

Tags: javascript, dojo

есть домбилд в нем фильтры и сохраненные значения фильтров. Я подключил эти фильтры к модальному окну. При нажатии на кнопку эти фильтры переносятся в открывающееся модальное окно. При повторном нажатии на кнопку фильтры сжимаются и должно закрываться модальное окно фильтры а возвращаться на сайт.

```
Dialog: function() {
        if (this.dom.classList.contains('short')){
            this.dialog.onCancel();
            return this.dom;
        } else {
            this.dialog.set('content', this.dom);
            this.dialog.show();
        }
        },
```

dom- это те самые фильтры. присваиваю их с помощью set. Как после закрытии окна вернуть значения обратно в dom. чтобы они выбрались из модального окна. Щас происходит я нажимаю на кнопку выходит модальное окно, с фильтрами, при повторном нажатии на кнопку окно пропадает вместе с фильтрами и этой кнопкой. Уже целый день пытаюсь решить проблему не выходит,не нашел как приделать скрины но фильтры выглядят как форма с кучей инпутов и чекбоксов, помогите плз. 
Переделал немного функцию

```
Dialog: function () {
        if (this.dom.classList.contains('short')) {
            this.dialog.onCancel();
        } else {
            this.dialog.set('content', this.dom);
            this.dialog.show();
        }
        this.repeatDom();
    },
    repeatDom: function () {
        if (this.dom.classList.contains('short')) {
            this.instaniateDom();
    }

    },
```

Только не могу понять как заставить выполняться repeatDom после закрытия this.dialog.onClose(); он повторяет дом еще в модальном окне а потом закрывает его.

Comment: тут точно тег java? мб все таки javascript?

Comment: Ой прошу прощения да здеь js просто заработался уже видимо совсем=)